# Can I add bathroom/closet in place of 2nd entry door?

Tags: bathroom, design, architecture

I have 1.5 bath ranch style house shown in picture below. The closet space is very limited and I really want to add one more full bath. I am contemplating closing the 2nd front door (as seen in sort of middle) with bathroom or at lease a closet. The bay style window is living and the corner room is the master bed, so the proposed bath could be attached master bed would would be great.

But does it sound like reasonable place to add bathroom? Will it be costly because it sort of outside of the existing living area? Alternatively would it be possible expand the house on right side and add bathroom/close there? What kind of cost are we talking about for that one?

Note, I do have the main entrance next to the garage. I don't think I will ever use the 2nd entrance and I have lawn in the back which is my main yard. This is the front of the house. I think I should use this space which otherwise I will hardly use. There is corridor part inside which could be part of it. Another of my concern with this is could bathroom be made sound proof enough so it can't be heard at all in the adjacent living room like flushing/showing etc? Could it look ugly from the front? If so that would kill the deal in the first place.

[image: front of house]

Comment: I don't see a vent stack on this side of the house, so the main consideration with a bathroom is going to be plumbing access.  Is the house on a full basement?

Comment: @Comintern Yes it does has full basement.

Answer (score 1):

Contact an local architect.  They will be able to create design drawings (and/or computer models), which will allow you to visualize the change.  This will allow you to make a more informed decision, than asking a bunch of dopes on the internet.

The architect should also be able to produce the blueprints, that can be used by a contractor to make the changes to your home.

Architects do charge for their services, but it's going to be much cheaper than building an addition you're not happy with.

Answer (score 0):

Check your town's rules. Some places require that any "living space" must have two egress routes, and they don't accept windows since that might not work for people with reduced mobility. Other areas seem to only require (or at least only enforce) this for rental spaces.

In the end, what matters is the opinion of the local inspectors.

If they say no, ask them whether you can build a small atrium/pantry/laundry room in front of that door. You may be able to get away with a walk-through closet as the second exit.